# What does `protected` mean in PHP?

Tags: php, inheritance, siblings

I was reading through some PHP code, and I noticed a class calling a protected method on its sibling (inherited from a common parent).  This strikes me as counter-intuitive.

Does `in the same inheritance tree` in PHP mean something [like Java's `part of the same package`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/215505/12570) ?

[I'm more used to the C# meaning of `protected`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx)

Because I am more used to C#'s meaning of protected, I was not expecting to be able to call the protected method on a sibling class.  In Java, the distinction is clear from the package.  Is there anything, other than inheritance, that defines accessibility in this instance in PHP?

```
<?

class C1
{
    protected function f()
    {
        echo "c1\n";
    }
}

class C2 extends C1
{
    protected function f()
    {
        echo "c2\n";
    }
}

class C3 extends C1
{
    public function f()
    {
        // Calling protected method on parent.
        $c1 = new C1();
        $c1 -> f();

        // Calling protected method on sibling??!?
        $c2 = new C2();
        $c2 -> f();

        echo "c3\n";
    }
}

$c3 = new C3();
$c3 -> f();

// OUTPUT:
// c1
// c2
// c3
```

Here's me trying to the same thing in C# (and failing).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class c1
    {
        protected void f()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("c1");
        }
    }
    class c2: c1
    {
        protected void f()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("c2");
        }
        public void g()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("g!");
        }
    }

    class c3 : c1
    {
        protected void f()
        {
            // Error    1   Cannot access protected member 'ConsoleApplication2.c1.f()' 
            //  via a qualifier of type 'ConsoleApplication2.c1'; the qualifier must be 
            // of type 'ConsoleApplication2.c3' (or derived from it)    
            //c1 cone = new c1();
            //cone.f();

            base.f();

            c2 ctwo = new c2();
            //Error 1   'ConsoleApplication2.c2.f()' is inaccessible due to its protection level
            ctwo.f();
            ctwo.g();


            Console.WriteLine("c3");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            c3 cthree = new c3();
            // Error    2   'ConsoleApplication2.c3.f()' is inaccessible due to its protection level
            cthree.f();
        }
    }
}
```

---

It looks like the behaviour expected was the case prior to PHP 5.2.  [This RFC explains the issue a little more](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/protectedlookup), and points to [why the change happened in this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37632).

I'm not sure it quite answers my question, but I thought I'd update the question, in case it helps anyone.

Thanks to Robin F., for [pointing me to this discussion of the RFC](http://marc.info/?t=120221202200001&r=1&w=2), for some background.

Comment: Try to search before asking > http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: @Svetlio: None of that answers my question, which is why I asked it here.  Except this addition: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#93743  Please read the question before posting.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why this sound weird to you... Could you explain it better? To me is all fine (and not counter intuitive)

Comment: @DonCallisto: See edit. Basically, because I am more used to C#'s version, and because PHP does not appear to use namespace / package definitions to restrict access as Java does.

Comment: C3 is not calling the protected method on sibling but the protected method on parent overrided by C2. If you try to call a protected method on C2 wich doesn't exist on C1, you've got a fatal error.

Comment: @PeterK. as I told you there is documentation. In C3 you have access to C1 methods and if you call it even from C2 you can access it.
Try dumping get_class_methods('C2') and you will find that there aren't C2 methods at $c2  "Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes"

Comment: @Svetlio But my example code contradicts "Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes". `C3` is not a parent of `C2` nor does it inherit from `C2`, and yet it is allowed to call a protected method.

Comment: see comment above ;) C3 is not allowed to call a protected method from C2

Comment: @scraaappy: OK... but why is it in my example code?

Comment: Hi! see my edit with an example from Java world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the behaviour expected was the case prior to PHP 5.2.  [This RFC explains the issue a little more](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/protectedlookup), and points to [why the change happened in this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37632).

I'm not sure it quite answers my question, but I thought I'd update the question, in case it helps anyone.

Thanks to Robin F., for [pointing me to this discussion of the RFC](http://marc.info/?t=120221202200001&r=1&w=2), for some background.

Answer (score 2):

To me there isn't nothing out-of-order. `protected` means visible to this class and all his subclasses.

Let's analyze this snippet

```
class C3 extends C1
{
  public function f()
  {
    // Calling protected method on parent.
    $c1 = new C1();
    $c1 -> f();

    // Calling protected method on sibling??!?
    $c2 = new C2();
    $c2 -> f();

    echo "c3\n";
  }
}
```

You're overwriting `C1->f()` [and this is fine] but first time you're recalling `$c1->f()` (as `$c1` is an instance of `C1` class) and so output is perfectly ok.
Second time you're calling `$c2->f()` so no sibling function but `C2` class function and this is perfectly legal as you're overwriting this too.

Maybe I don't understand properly your question, but this is the explaination of the above snippet of code

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm still not getting it, though. The call in `$c2 -> f()` is coming from class `C3`, which (to my way of C# thinking) should not be possible for protected methods.

Comment: @PeterK. : are you sure that this example, writte in c# language, provide a different result? (I'm asking because I don't remember well C# underlying mechanisms; and I'm not sure about what you're saying here)

Comment: Done!  As you can see, the IDE keeps saying `'f()' is inaccessible due to its protection level`

Comment: @PeterK.: ok now I can see it... Yes it seems different from c# world

Answer (score -1):

According to Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Php):

> Objects of the same type have access to each other's private and protected members even though they are not the same instance.

**EDIT:**

See code snippet (in **Java**):

```
public class SimpleApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleApp s = new SimpleApp();
        s.method(); // interesting?!
    }

    private void method() {
        System.out.println("This is private method!");
    }
}
```

When run, in the console there will be message displayed.
I guess this is because of how compilator (or for **PHP** interpreter) is implemented.

In this case you are inside SimpleApp class, so you can call its private method (even on different object - from outside). It might be different for **C#**.

Comment: But `C3` is not the same type as `C2`.

Comment: C2 and C3 are both C1.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks... that's different from what I'm used to (see edited question with C# example).

Comment: This is the same as C#. All you are doing is calling a private member from within the class: no problem. Java is the same as my C# example in the question.